# Setting up Helm RBAC Per Namespace

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-helm

I'm following the official Helm [documentation](https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#role-based-access-control) for "Deploy Tiller in a namespace, restricted to deploying resources only in that namespace". Here is my bash script:

```
Namespace="$1"

kubectl create namespace $Namespace
kubectl create serviceaccount "tiller-$Namespace" --namespace $Namespace
kubectl create role "tiller-role-$Namespace" /
    --namespace $Namespace /
    --verb=* /
    --resource=*.,*.apps,*.batch,*.extensions
kubectl create rolebinding "tiller-rolebinding-$Namespace" /
    --namespace $Namespace /
    --role="tiller-role-$Namespace" /
    --serviceaccount="$Namespace:tiller-$Namespace"
helm init /
    --service-account "tiller-$Namespace" /
    --tiller-namespace $Namespace
    --override "spec.template.spec.containers[0].command'='{/tiller,--storage=secret}"
    --upgrade
    --wait
```

Running `helm upgrade` gives me the following error:

> Error: UPGRADE FAILED: configmaps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list configmaps in the namespace "kube-system"

Is there a bug in the official documentation? Have I read it wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `$ helm init --service-account <serviceaccount_name> --tiller-namespace <namespace> --upgrade` to upgrade your existing `tiller`?

Comment: Added the command I'm using for `helm init`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about `--resource` flag correct syntax in your script, whether asterisk symbols "*" are allowed here, look at this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62989) reported on GitHub.

```
$ kubectl create role "tiller-role-$Namespace" \
--namespace $Namespace \
--verb=* \
--resource=*.,*.apps,*.batch,*.extensions
the server doesn't have a resource type "*"
```

But you can check this role object in your cluster:

`kubectl get role tiller-role-$Namespace -n $Namespace -o yaml`

Otherwise, try to create the role for `tiller` within yaml file as guided in the documentation:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: tiller-manager
  namespace: tiller-world
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "batch", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

Moreover, keep in mind that if you have installed `tiller` in the non-default namespace (`default`), it is necessary to specify namespace where `tiller` resides on, when you invoke `Helm` command:

```
$ helm --tiller-namespace $Namespace version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.11.0", GitCommit:"2e55dbe1fdb5fdb96b75ff144a339489417b146b", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.11.0", GitCommit:"2e55dbe1fdb5fdb96b75ff144a339489417b146b", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```